# Best way to burn OS to Disc on Mac?

Tags: macos, images, dvd, operating-systems, burning

How to burn an OS like Windows 7 onto a DVD for Mac? What software should be used? Is Toast good enough and if so, how do I make the DVD bootable?

Comment: Are you talking about taking an iso image file representing Windows 7, or a *live copy of Windows* which you want to want to 'burn' onto a DVD for use in a Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, toast is fine.

- Open toast and select **Copy**
- Choose **image file** from the options
- Click on **select** and navigate to the ISO image and click **choose** once you select it
- Click the big red burn button in the bottom right corner
- Insert a blank DVD into the drive, select the proper drive in the dropdown menu, and hit **Record**. The default settings do not need to be changed.

If the ISO image was bootable, the DVD will be bootable.

Comment: No comments, as expected :)

Comment: There's no reason to downgrade this answer, it's a reasonable answer with the information given to him from the question. The question explicitly mentioned Toast, so he gave the methodology of burning an iso from toast.

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming the you are working with an .iso?

If so the best way is to use 'Disk Utility'. Can't remember the exact method (im not on my mac), but from memory you can create a new image, select the iso file and there is an option to burn to disk.

Hope this helps

edit: this process is outlined [here](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20060619181010389)

Comment: any website that could outline this process?

Comment: see update to above post

Answer (score 1):

**[LiquidCD](http://www.maconnect.ch/)** is a brilliant free Disc Burning Suite for Mac OS X, of course it can be used to burn ISO to disc.

[image]